# jQuery, execute function on document load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code is my attempt to pop up a message to any user visiting the page (Which is only for IE users).

```
<script src="jquery.reject.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.reject({  
        reject: { all: true },
        header: 'Internet Explorer is NOT Supported!',
        paragraph1: 'You will not be able to blah blah blah.',  
        paragraph2: 'Please choose one of the browsers below for this to function.',
        closeMessage: 'Note: You can still blah blah blah.'
    });      
    return false;  
});
</script>
```

What is wrong with the code? There are no syntax errors, but nothing happens when the page is loaded.

Thank you.

EDIT: Line 4, fixed to what it currently is. Still fails though.

Comment: I don't think you need to `return false`, but apart from that it looks okay (assuming that the plug-in itself advises that particular layout/functions and so forth.

Comment: Did the *reject.js* script get loaded properly?

Comment: <script src="jquery.reject.js"></script>
Meaning that the file is in the same folder as index.php? Which it is.

Comment: Are you importing the base jQuery library so the browser even knows what to do with $ ?

Comment: Also, I think Siku means, did you check the console to make sure the file is actually getting loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo on line 4, you have `"$jquery.reject"` instead of `"$.reject"` or `"jquery.reject"`

EDIT: if someone ever gets here again, there were a couple things wrong with the origin post, first a typo, then a missing reference to jquery and then another missing reference to the CSS for the plugin.

Comment: Are you loading both jquery and jquery.reject?

Comment: No, what I posted in my original post is exactly the beginning of the document. After that, it's just PHP.

Comment: You need to load jQuery before you load the plugin.

Comment: I was going after this: http://jreject.turnwheel.com/#demo2 I just enabled loading jQuery before the reject, and it works. But not correctly. Try for yourself using IE, at http://plz.re (Much different than the demo on that site.

Comment: I don't have IE on my machine (running Ubuntu), did you already added the CSS for the plugin? http://jreject.turnwheel.com/css/jquery.reject.css if not, the plugin might work but look totally weird.

Comment: Wow, I'm stupid. I was calling the CSS from the main page, not the one for IE. Thanks, it works now.

Comment: You are welcome, can you check my answer as the valid one :)?

Answer (score 0):

`jquery.reject.js` is a jQuery plugin.  You need to load jQuery first, for example:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: I did, following the comment on the post below by LEOPiC, which is <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> currently. The page loads, the script fires, but it's not displayed correctly.